SwiftUI List selection on Mac gives console warning about "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed"
I am working on a SwiftUI List with selection where the 'selection' is based on a viewModel object that is a @ObservableObject. It works, but produces this warning in the console:

Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will
cause undefined behavior

This warning only comes on the Mac, when running on device (not in Preview), and not when running the same exact code on iOS.
Here is the code to reproduce this issue, based on the Core Data template project:
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

final class SelectionModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published public var selectedItems = Set<Item.ID>()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SelectionModel = SelectionModel()
    //@State var selectedItems = Set<Item.ID>() // using this works without the console warning
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(selection: $viewModel.selectedItems) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()

#Preview {
    ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
}

Is this something to be concerned about, and/or is there a way to avoid it, while still using an ObservableObject? I can't move to @Observable because I still need to support iOS16.

Have you tried using
@StateObject var viewModel = SelectionModel()

That didn't help.

Change SelectionModel to struct and use @State. It is unusual to have a struct with only one var though.

That didn't help either, because then I can't use ObservableObject. In my main app, I have different variables in the ObservableObject that I didn't include in the sample. However, I played around with it, and removing @Published for selectedItems works, which would be OK for my use-case, though I'm confused as to 'why' it works for list selection
